# contour deformation in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I have a contour map and I want to make a deformation of all the contour lines,  where the contour of level 0.5 will be deformed around the blue point situated in his line and then pass on the blue point on the contour of level 1, and so on.

Original map :
[image: original map]

Deformed map :
[image: deformed map]

I think there are two steps, the first one is the delete some parts of the map and the second is to redraw the contour map.

I think i have to iterate through the contour map like this:

```
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
for level in CS.collections:
    for kp, path in list(enumerate(level.get_paths())):
```

But I have no idea how to use `kp` and `path`

Any tips for doing this would be appreciated!

Comment: Modifying the path of an existing contour is not the right approach. Instead you need to modify the underlying data and readraw the contour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you could change the contour plot to achieve the intended deformation.
It generates some data `x,y,z` which should later be modified. Then it specifies a deformation function, which when multiplied to `z` deforms the data in the desired way. This deformation function takes the `x` and `y` data as input as well as the angle of the line along which to perform the deformation and a width (spread) of the deformation. Finally a parameter `i` is used for stearing the degree of deformation (i.e. `i=0` means no deformation). Of course you can use any other function to deform your contour.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation

#### generate some x,y,z data ####
r = np.linspace(0,6,  num=100)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num=200)
R, Phi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)
x = R*np.cos(Phi)
y = R*np.sin(Phi)
z = R
##################################

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")

def update(i):
    ax.clear()
    f = lambda x,y, offs, width, i: 1-i*np.exp(-(np.arctan2(x,y)-offs)**2/width)  
    z_deformed = z*f(x,y, np.pi/4, 1./8., i=i)
    ax.contour(x,y,z_deformed, 10, linewidths=4)
    ax.contourf(x,y,z_deformed, 10, alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
    ax.set_ylim([-4,4])

update(0) #plot the original data
anipath = 0.5*np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=20))**2
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=anipath, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

Of course you can use other shapes of deformation. E.g. to get a triangular shape use

```
f = lambda x, A, a, b: A*(1.-np.abs((x-b)/a))*(np.abs((x-b)) < a )
z_deformed = z - f(np.arctan2(x,y), i, 1./8., np.pi/4 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in my problem i don't have the function of the contour map. I just have some data (x,y,z) and a line (2 points) and I have to make a deformation along this line. And I shouldn't add any new data, just change the actual data

Comment: You don't need the function of the contour map. I edited the answer, rearanging the some of the commands to make it clearer that the function in use is independent of the `x,y,z`-data. Of course to produce this example I need to generate some data, but they don't rely on any function that is later used.

Comment: Yes I see now. I used your  function on a random data and it deformed all the contour, however I want just to deform a part of it along a line. It works fine on the circles data though.

Comment: It should work for any kind of data that sits on a grid. Since it's unclear what *"random data"* and *"deformed all the contour"* means, it hard to tell what's happening. I suppose you're anyways not working with random data, so in how far does it not work with the data you are having?

Comment: By deform all the contours, I mean to change the contour level bit around a point. By using your solution, I can't control the new shape of the contour line. I found one way to do it, here is my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c97ad72f338731643e083bbbb49d844 , as you can see the new shape of each contour line is changed according to a line

Comment: Changing the shape requires a different function to use. I edited the question, to show how to use a triangular shape.

Comment: What if I wanted a different shape for each contour level? this method won't work I guess

Comment: As long as the countours would carry a meaning in the sense that they represent some field on a grid, there will be a functional way to deform the field's shape. Once you give up that requirement, i.e. the lines in the plot do not represent anything meaningful, there will be cases, where you won't find a function to produce the desired shape. However in the latter case, it's definitely questionable why to use a contourplot at all and not simply draw a path of the required shape to the canvas.